# Regex ignore space with special characters using {, }, $ and @

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to get a regex to match an exact word as part of a keyword replacement. I have the following statements to test it against (the word here is "Foo" (case sensitive)):

```
foo.  
foo  
foos  
 foo .  
 foo.  
@{foo}  
Foo.  
Foo space  
Foo  
Foo.  
 Foo .  
  Foo.  
@{Foo}  
${Foo}
```

Now I have gotten close with:

```
\b(?![(\@|\$)\{])Foo\b
```

and

> \bFoo\b

But I can't get it to negate on

@{Foo} or ${Foo} If I try and use

```
[^(\@\{)]\bFoo\b
```

It just matches the leading whitespace where it doesn't match previously. My Regex-Fu is weak here and I could really appreciate a good solution, especially one that can explain how!

Comment: Which flavor (language) of regex are you working with?

Comment: Regex statement within C#

Comment: Just to understand, you want it to only match `Foo` with no spaces or special characters?

Comment: Why are you using a character class combined with an OR?  I'm not intimately familiar with C# regex, but shouldn't it be `\b(?!(@|\$|\{))Foo\b` I don't think the `@` needs to be escaped either.

Comment: I think I slightly misunderstood your issue.  However, the `@` comment remains valid. Also, I still don't think you need the character class notation there.

Comment: To update, I think `\b(?!(@|\$)\{)Foo\b` will work.  However, I cannot test it and thus won't post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(?<![(@|\$)\{])\bFoo\b
```

The trouble with `[^(\@\{)]` is that it matches any character that isn't in that set, where as you want to check that the character isn't in that set without actually matching it.

`(?<!yourmatch)` is a negative look behind, it checks for the presence of a pattern without matching it.

Comment: This is failing the validation I mentioned by falsly approving @{Foo} and ${Foo}

Comment: don't have c# here so only tested using http://www.myregextester.com/?r=b80cfa99. Apologies

Comment: This isn't a matter of escaping that `@` sign is it?

Comment: perhaps. updating without the escapes

Comment: Well the other escapes seem necessary.  Just the @ symbol isn't a special regex character as far as I know.

Comment: pretty sure in JS you wouldn't need to escape the $ or { when they're within a [...].  Considering this regex compiles at all I'm surprised it would match @{Foo}

Comment: Considering the question is about c#, http://www.regexhero.net/tester produces the same matches for both: ``(?<![(@|\$)\{])\bFoo\b`` (OGHaza) and ``(?<![\@\$]\{)Foo`` (my "version"). And those matches don't include any of the unwanted parts.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll update and test it and let you know which one works so I can note the answer

Comment: The edited answer was enough for what I needed, there was an edge case on having a pipe in the name, but have removed it as an edge case the multilingual processing can deal with